# Explode with delimiter and loop the result

Tags: php

Hi i wonder how can i echo out the results of the exploded string with delimiter.

```
$beng = explode(";", $row['smsmsg']);
for($i=0;$i>=9;$i++){
echo $beng[$i];
$i+++;
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi, Your for loop should be ```php for($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) { ... }```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$beng = explode(";", $row['smsmsg']);
 foreach($beng as $key => $value){
    echo $value;
 }
```

Comment: Think you meant `foreach`.